# Hibernate one to many mapping skipping relationship

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

Suppose i am having a one to many relationships between employee and address entity . Is it possible to create employee alone first and then update the employee mapping with the address later..

Tq

Comment: It's possible, but you not explain what's your problem trying to do that and also you not share your entities code. We need more details about your problem to help you.

Comment: Pls help  me on hiw to do it

Comment: add the code that you have so far

Answer (score 0):

You can add a cascade to the `@OneToMany` relationship.  You can use `CascadeType.PERSIST` which will update the child entity when it is modified and the parent entity is saved.

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
  ...
  @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
  private Set<Address> addresses;
  ...
}

@Entity
public class Address{
  ...
}
```

Now you can save/persist a new employee without any `Address`.  When you want to add an address you can query for the employee, add a new address, then save the updated employee. The new address entity will be persisted with the employee.

Here is a nice write up going over cascades with JPA

> https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/